# String search into html

Tags: javascript, string, full-text-search

I'm trying to find some text in a long string but my code does not work, For Example:

```
Var result = “<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC -//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN html><head<title>Hey i am here</title>”

if (result.search('Hey i am here')== true) {
alert('found');
} else { alert('NOT found'); }
```

But This dont Works :(
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thinks you need to use an .indexOf function.

so your if statement would be

```
if (results.indexOf('Hey i am here') != -1) {
   alert('found');
} else { alert('NOT found'); }
```

There are a lot of ways to do this:
[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/javascript-string-contains)

Answer (score 1):

1. `var` is **lower case**
2. Strings can be delimited with `"` or `'` but not with `“`, don't use curly quotes.
3. The `search` method expects a regular expression (although it will try to convert a string if it gets one)
4. If you want a simple string match, then `indexOf` is more efficient then `search`.
5. Both `search` and `indexOf` return the *index* of the first match (or `-1` if it doesn't find one), not a boolean.

As an aside, that Doctype will trigger quirks mode, so never use it in a real HTML document.

```
var result = "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC -//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN html><head<title>Hey i am here</title>"

if (result.indexOf("Hey i am here") >= 0) {
    alert('found');
} else { 
    alert('NOT found'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Search` method returns the position of the match, or -1 if no match is found. Not `true` or `false`.